# how to get selected info in wrappanel in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

First, let's look at a piece of code like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="500" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="b" TargetType="Border">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="200" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <WrapPanel>
        <Border Style="{StaticResource b}" />
        <Border Style="{StaticResource b}" />
        <Border Style="{StaticResource b}" />
        <Border Style="{StaticResource b}" />
    </WrapPanel>
</Window>
```

Then, the effect I want to achieve is that When I click a Border,the Border's bordercolor changes to red,if there was an other Border I clicked before,this Border's bordercolor would be black(equivalent to changing back to the original color).

The feasible method I have come up with so far is that bind a mouseclick RoutedEvent to each border, and let the wrappanel listen to this event. When the event is triggered, let the wrappanel traverse its children. If there is a child's name equals the event source's name, change this border color and don't forget setting all other children to black.

But I think this approach is a bit troublesome. Is there a more elegant and simple way to handle it?(Do not use mvvm or other frameworks)

In addition, I tried an idea, that is, when the border is clicked, assign the name of the border to the datacontext of the wrappanel, and then set the datatrigger for the borders. The condition is that the datacontext of the wrappanel is the same as the border's name. However, after testing, this is not possible.The value of "value" cannot be {binding ...}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a ListBox with a WrapPanel as `ItemsPanel` and the most simple `ItemContainerStyle` without all the standard item state visualization.

Add a `DataTrigger` to the Border Style that binds to the `IsSelected` state of the ListBoxItem container of each Border. You also have to add a transparent `Background` to make the Border hit-test visible.

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="b" TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="200"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                    Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"
                    Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Border Style="{StaticResource b}"/>
    <Border Style="{StaticResource b}"/>
    <Border Style="{StaticResource b}"/>
    <Border Style="{StaticResource b}"/>
</ListBox>
```

You may alternatively move the Border into the `ItemContainerStyle`, but then you would have to add some kind of data items to the ListBox's `Items` or `ItemsSource` collection, e.g. a string with four characters as shown below.

Instead of a `DataTrigger` in the Border Style, you could now use a somewhat simpler `Trigger` on the `IsSelected` property in the ControlTemplate.

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         ItemsSource="1234">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border x:Name="border" Width="200" Height="200"
                                Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Black"
                                BorderThickness="2" Margin="4"/>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="border"
                                        Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Most certainly you would now use a collection of real data items as the ItemsSource, and show item data in the Border via a ContentPresenter child element.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't have to iterate over the child elements in order to identify the event source. The event handler of the routed event and `RoutedEventArgs` exposes the direct hit source via the `sender` parameter, `RoutedEventArgs.OriginalSource` property and the `RoutedEventArgs.Source` property. The `sender` returns the element that the event handler was registered with, whereas  `OriginalSource` returns the element that is the event source determined by hit testing and `Source` the event source. `Source` can differ if the event was e.g. re-raised along the route. For example, when your `Border` has registered a `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` event handler and contains a `Button` and the `Button` was clicked, then the `RoutedEventArgs.OriginalSource` will return the `Button` and the `sender` the `Border`.

Next, you can omit the `Style.Setters` property when you define setters:

```
<Style>
  <Setter... />
</Style>
```

Then you should set the `Border.Background` to `Transparent` to allow clicking the empty area within. Otherwise, you would have to exactly click on child elements or the border line itself.

One solution is to handle the routed mouse up event:

```xml
<WrapPanel x:Name="WrapPanel">
  <WrapPanel.Style>
    <Style x:Key="b" TargetType="Border">
      <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"
                   Handler="Border_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" />
      <Setter Property="Background"
              Value="Transparent" />
 
    ...

  </Style>

  <Border Style="{StaticResource b}" />
  <Border Style="{StaticResource b}" />
  <Border Style="{StaticResource b}" />
  <Border Style="{StaticResource b}" />
</WrapPanel>
```

```cs
private void Border_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  // Reset all border elements
  foreach (Border border in this.WrapPanel.Children.OfType<Border>())
  {
    border.Background = Brushes.Black;
  }

  // Change background of clicked border
  var selectedBorder = (Border)sender;
  selectedBorder.Background = Brushes.Orange;

  // OriginalSource or Source depends on the scenario
  var clickedBorderChild = e.OriginalSource;
}
```

Another solution (I think a better one) is to use a `ListBox` instead. You can replace the default panel with the `WrapPanel`. Then you easily get the selected item by referencing the `ListBox.SelectedItem` property. You can implement style triggers to toggle the background based on the selectionstate. I will not post an example again as the [answer of Clemens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78160569/3141792) gives you two alternatives.:

Comment: This method is more in line with my previous thinking of developing winform, but I prefer to use xaml to solve logical problems on the UI (otherwise why would I want to learn wpf), so maybe Clemens' answer is more suitable for me, sorry~

Comment: Don't say sorry. Clemens answer is what I suggest too. I just posted this to show how you can avoid the iteration to identify the event clicked element by handling the routed event properly. My intent was to show how to properly handle routed events and then to show how to use a ListBox. But while I was writing Clemens was faster. So I decided to skip that part and link to Clemens' answer as the recommended solution.